# Overcome 1 Interface limitation for projected classes to Javascript using Chakra?

Tags: c#, uwp, chakra

I have a problem with the limitation of only having the 1st interface projected to Javascript. I would like to know if there are any workarounds / methods of solving it.

I have around 20 classes I want to access in Javascript. These 20 classes inherit from a BaseModel, which contains code that are important and used by all 20 classes. Below is a simple example:

```
public class Category : BaseModel
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}

public class Item : BaseModel
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Price {get;set;}
}

public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IParentableViewModel
{
    //Some Important Methods that are shared between around 20 Models
}
```

If I want to access it in Javascript, I would have to create BaseModel for ALL 20 of the classes. This is because Javascript can only see the properties / methods of the 1st Interface. So then my code becomes something like:

```
public class CategoryBaseModel : ICategoryModel, INotifyPropertyChanged, IParentableViewModel
{
    //Important Methods gets duplicated between CategoryBaseModel and ItemBaseModel making it harder to maintain
}

public class ItemBaseModel : IItemModel, INotifyPropertyChanged, IParentableViewModel
{
    //Important Methods gets duplicated between CategoryBaseModel and ItemBaseModel making it harder to maintain
}
```

Which becomes hard to maintain, especially since I have around 20 methods.

I am looking if I can override the setter for Javascript but not sure how to do it. The idea is this:

```
//I want to override something like this. 
//whenever I call category.someProperty = someValue; in Javascript, it goes through this.
//When it goes through this, I can then call the SetProperty method for unknown properties in the interface
public bool JavaScriptPropertySet(object, propertyName, Value)
{
    if(object.hasProperty(propertyName))
    {
        //Set PropertyName
    }
    else
    {
        object.setProperty(propertyName, Value);
    }
}
```

And then I can define my classes to be simpler like this:

```
public interface IBaseViewModel
{
    string Title {get;set;}
    void SetProperty(propertyName, Value);
}

public class BaseModel : IBaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged, IParentableViewModel
{
    //important methods

    public void SetProperty(propertyName, Value)
    {
        SetPropertyInternal(propertyName, Value);
    }

    public virtual void SetPropertyInternal(propertyName, Value)
    {
    }
}

public class Category : BaseModel
{
    public override void SetPropertyInternal(propertyName, Value)
    {
        if(propertyName == 'description')
            this.description = Value;
    }
}
```

Is there such a way?

Thank you

Comment: Are you developing a UWP app with WinJS? OR hosting JavaScript in a UWP app?

Comment: Hosting Javascript in a UWP App. Specifically, we are using ChakraBridge. https://github.com/deltakosh/JsBridge